# How to find from where the print function is called?

Tags: python

During program execution I recieve some print messages in console with depreciated information. The former coders left several `print` lines somewhere in the program and I want to get rid of them:

```
# module N123456

......
print var123
......
```

The problem is that the program is quite heavy and consists of many-many large modules. Is there some simple way to determine where these annoying prints located?

Thanks!

Comment: grep search for "print"?

Comment: In vi, use `/print`. If you know what's printing, you can also search for what the print statements are printing, again using the forward slash

Comment: @cadams this is quite difficult.. there are too many useful prints along the code and unfortunately all the redundant `print` usually print only some numeric values of variables or their combination...

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque The literal `'print'` can be found in a relevant string.

Comment: @funnypony Sorry bud, but there's not really any easy way to do this unless you can find some attribute that's unique to those statements. Maybe try contacting the former coders to see if they can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

Do a search and replace, as Vivek Anand suggested, but instead of commenting out the `print` lines, add `; print __file__` to them, and see where that gets you.

You could also run the program through a debugger, initially stepping over the functions and paying attention to when spurious `print`s are appearing. That may help you pinpoint the places where they come from (but it depends on the structure of the program, you might end up having to go over many lines of code, one by one).

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea! In addition to filename it is possible to add current line number also.. and that really simplifies the whole deal!

Answer (score 1):

Just use find and replace. Find 'print' and replace it with '#print'. This is if you are using vim.

```
:%s/print/#print/ig
```

This would comment them out

Comment: but this will also comment all other useful prints, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it does. But, i can't think of any other way. The best idea that i can think of is to find all the print 's (generally highlighted when you put them in search) and go on checking if you need them or not. Find and replace usage depends on number of print 's that you need and number of them you don't.

Comment: yes, I think that is the only way too... but as the program is huge, and with threads, so these prints appears more or less accidentally.. this could take several days to remove it.